# Closure of the range of a map

Tags: general-topology, functions

Let $f\colon E\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ a certain function and let $X\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ not open. Assume that $\operatorname{range} f\subset X$, I need to prove that $\overline{\operatorname{range} f}\subset X$. To me it's enough to prove that for every sequence $\{e_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$ of points in $E$ such that $e_k\rightarrow \infty$, and such that $y_k=f(e_k)$ converges, then $y_k\rightarrow y\in X$.

Thanks!

Comment: The claim is obviously false. Let $n=1$ and $E = X = [0,1)$ as well as $f(x) = x$. Then $\overline{range(f)} = [0,1]$ which is not a subset of $X = [0,1)$.

Comment: I'm not saying that it is a general property, I need to show this for a given function and I am wondering on how to do that. Thanks!

Comment: But then why don't you tell what the particular function is that?

Comment: It's too much complicated since it's the solution to a certain hybrid dynamical systems. I'd like to have an insight on how to do in general.

Comment: And why do you choose $e_k\to\infty$? Actually, you didn't tell what $E$ is, so $e_k\to\infty$ might not even make sense. What is your question actually? If you want a clear answer, ask a clear question.

Comment: You're right. The set $E$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{N}$. Anyway my question wants to be general. In particular, given a function $f$ mapping a certain topological space into another one, what are the points included in $\overline{range f}$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Isn't the function

$$\;f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R\;,\;\;f(x):=\begin{cases}\frac1x,&|x|>1\\1,&|x|\le1\end{cases}$$

with $\;X=(0,1]\;$ , a counterexample? Here, clearly $\;f(\Bbb R)\subset X\;$ , yet $\;\overline{f(\Bbb R)}\rlap{\;\,/}\subset X\;$ since

$$\;\forall\,2<n\in\Bbb N\;,\;f(n)=\frac1n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0\notin X\;$$

Comment: This somewhat gives credit to my idea of using sequence...